# Why does this dataframe variable take an attribute not explicity assigned to it? (dplyr-R)

Tags: r, dplyr, attr

Curious: can someone give the explanation as to why df1 and df3 are finally assigned the same attribute even though df3 is the one explicitly modified? I would have assumed that because df1 and df3 have different memory addresses they would not be both modified. Piping issue?--How are objects being bound together?

```
library(lobstr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3])
df2<-data.frame(df1)

df3<-df2%>% dplyr::mutate_at(vars(ends_with("x")),
                   funs(data.table::setattr(.,"label","An x column")))

str(df1)
str(df3)

obj_addr(df1)
obj_addr(df3)
```

Results

```
 str(df1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3
 ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "An x column"
 $ y: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
str(df3)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3
 ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "An x column"
$ y: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3

obj_addr(df1)
[1] "0xafe6a98"
obj_addr(df3)
[1] "0x98deef0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation for `setattr`:

> In data.table, all set* functions change their input by reference.
>   That is, no copy is made at all, other than temporary working memory
>   which is as large as one column. The only other data.table operator
>   that modifies input by reference is :=. Check out the See Also section
>   below for other set* function that data.table provides.

If you want to specify attributes with the normal copy-on-modify semantics you can use `structure`:

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_at(vars(ends_with("x")), funs(structure(., label = "An x column")))
```

Comment: Thank you! I also saw the same issue I think using `Hmisc` or `haven` I can't remember which now. But I couldn't try it with `structure` now either--"package ‘structure’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)"

Comment: `structure` is a base R function